# Default mapping and additional servlets

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

is is possible, without setting the default vaadin mapping (vaadin.urlMapping), to add additional servlets (rest apis, swagger)? Currently all requests are forwarded to vaadin.

The same question was ask by another user here: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17784969/is-it-possible-to-configure-the-vaadin-servlet-to-ignore-certain-requests

Thanks for your help!
Thomas

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot RestControllers etc are working fine. But if the tool (Swagger) is not "correctly" registered it will not work and then you have to set the vaadin url

Comment: Hello Simon! That's correct. The RestController are working fine, but a additional WebMvcConfigurer with resource handler getting no access. How can I fix this? And how do I have to configure the swagger "correctly"? Thanks, Thomas

Comment: I found the issue on https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/602 . It seems there is no solution, right?

Comment: As far as I know there is no solution.